# How Can I Customize Magento Default URL (Product URL and Category URL)

Tags: magento-1.9, url, url-rewrite, catalog-url-rewrite

Suppose i have the following URL:

For Categories (example : apparels category):
http://example/apparels.html

For Categories (example : product under apparels category):
http://example/apparels/songket-batik-merah.html

I'd like to know how can i rewrite the above URLS so that for category URL it can contains '/category/' and for product URL it can contains '/product/' so the end result would become something like this :

http://example/category/apparels.html

http://example/product/songket-batik-merah.html

I know one solution for this is by doing it manually for each Category / Product via Back Office > Catalog > URL Rewrite.

Is there a better way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Magento gives you the ability to add the name of categories to path for product URL’s.

If you want to remove then follow below setting.

To do this, go to `System => Configuration => Catalog => Catalog => Search Engine Optimization` and set `Use categories path for product URL’s` to `no`.

and for category 
Select `no` from `Use Parent Category Path for Category URLs`

Comment: Thanks for the help, i am afraid i am unable to locate "Use Parent Category Path for Category URLs" on System > Configuration > Catalog > Catalog > Search Engine Optimization. Can you elaborate more on this ?